# Is it possible to pass arguments to `runhaskell` using a Heredoc?

Tags: shell, haskell, heredoc, runhaskell

I would like to pass the string "Hello World" to the following Haskell script:

```
main :: IO ()
main = interact id
```

that sits inside a Heredoc. Is that possible ?

I have made a minimal reproducible example (does not currently work):

```hs
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World" | runhaskell <<HASKELL_END 2>/dev/null
main :: IO ()
main = interact id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if it's okay for you to use zsh.

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "Hello World" | runghc =(cat <<'HASKELL_END'
main :: IO ()
main = interact id
HASKELL_END
)
```

or

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "Hello World" | runghc =(<<<'
main :: IO ()
main = interact id'
)
```

The thing is, you need to pass your source code as a file since `interact` closes stdin. Unfortunately, process substitution in bash doesn't work well since ghc tries to get a size of the named pipe.

So this doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World" | runghc <(cat <<HASKELL_END
main :: IO ()
main = interact id
HASKELL_END
)
```

It gives this error.

```
*** Exception: /dev/fd/63: hFileSize: inappropriate type (not a regular file)
```

Of course, you can create a temporary file and delete it manually just like `(= )` does internally.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. Could you tell me where is `(= )` documented ?

Comment: You can find it here. https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution